# BOOL algebra : simplifications

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have this expression : 
(A && B) || (A && C) || (B && C)

I don't understand which steps I need to to to get this expression :

(A && B) || (C &&  (A XOR B))

Comment: You sure it's not just (C && (A||B)), using OR instead of XOR?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach for an example as small as this is just to construct and compare the truth tables.

Algebraically, however, we can do
$$\begin{align}&(A\land B)\lor(A\land C)\lor(B\land C)\\
\Leftrightarrow&(A\land B)\lor\big((A\lor B)\land C\big)\\
\Leftrightarrow&(A\land B)\lor\big(\neg(A\land B)\land ((A\lor B)\land C\big))\\
\Leftrightarrow&(A\land B)\lor\big((\neg(A\land B)\land (A\lor B))\land C\big)\\
\Leftrightarrow&(A\land B)\lor\big((A\oplus B)\land C\big) \\
\Leftrightarrow&(A\land B)\lor\big(C\land(A\oplus B))
\end{align}$$
where the second step used the general law
$$\begin{align}&P\lor Q\\
\Leftrightarrow&P\lor (1\land Q)\\
\Leftrightarrow&P\lor ((P\lor\neg P)\land Q)\\
\Leftrightarrow&P\lor ((P\land Q) \lor (\neg P\land Q))\\
\Leftrightarrow&(P\lor (P\land Q)) \lor (\neg P\land Q)\\
\Leftrightarrow&P \lor (\neg P\land Q)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer ! Still, I don't understand why line (2) is algebraically equivalent to line (3).

Comment: I've added the appropriate lemma.

Comment: I must be stupid but I don't get it. I understand the development of the general law but I can't make the relation with the development above. I have : A∨B = ... = A∨(¬A∧B) which is not equals to ¬(A∧B)∧(A∨B) ...

Comment: It's just $P=(A\land B)$ and $Q=((A\lor B)\land C)$.

Comment: Now it makes sense ! Thanks again !